# How to remove or unfriend through API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is database structure
[image]
This is API

```html
Route::post('/friend', 'FriendController@index');
Route::post('/removerequest/{id}', 'FriendController@removerequest');
```

This is controller code which into friend request method and remove method, but error in remove friend method..

```html
 public function index(Request $request) {
       
        $sender = Friend::where('sender_id', $request->sender_id)->where('receiver_id',$request->receiver_id)->first();
        if(empty($sender)){
            Friend::create(['sender_id'=>$request->sender_id,'receiver_id'=>$request->receiver_id, 'approved'=>'pending']);
            
            $response = ['message'=>'Friend Request has been sent','status'=>200];
            return response()->json($response);
        }else{
            $response = ['message'=>'Request has been sent already','status'=>200];
            return response()->json($response);
        }
        
    }
    public function removerequest($id){
       $friends = Friend::all()
                    ->where('receiver_id')
                    ->where('sender_id')
                    ->approved('accept')
                    ->delete();
            
    }
```

Error is

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::approved does not exist. in file /home/ynvih0l26evc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php on line 104
enter code here
```

Comment: in where condition you should pass the condition. `->where('receiver_id',$receiver_id)
                    ->where('sender_id', $sender_id)->where('approved','accept');`

Comment: How can i use particular field condition? bcoz i put condition approved == accept than show error...so i want to know how can i use perfect way? -@DilipHirapara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `Route` to

```
Route::delete('/removerequest/{id}', 'FriendController@removerequest');

//change 
->approve('approved', 'accept')
```

to

```
->where('approved', 'accept')
```

Update your controller method to

```
public function removerequest($id){
        $friends = Friend::Find($id)->delete(); //see update here
                    //->where('receiver_id')
                    //->where('sender_id')
                    //->where('approved', 'accept')
                    //->delete();

    }
```

OR

```
public function removerequest($id){
     Friend::where( ['id' => $id, 'approved' => 'accept'])->delete();   
}
```

Comment: Show me error BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist. -@codervine

Comment: is your `Route` a delete route?

Comment: yes Route::delete('/removerequest/{id}', 'FriendController@removerequest');
-codervine

Comment: I will update my answer now, just try the new one and let me know if it works... we will know what to do after which

Comment: your update answer specific id delete, its work -@codervine

Comment: now you don't have a `sender_id` and a `receiver_id` in that request. Do you intend deleting `id` where `sender_id` and `receiver_id` are not empty?

Comment: Its not depend on id, its friend request so depend on sender_id or receiver_id...do you understand ? -@codervine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204644/discussion-between-codervine-and-kinnu123).